# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in line 25

Tags: php, json

I am building a function and there is an error please help me to resolve this.

The error line is this:-

> Parse error:syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/u854338141/public_html/login/register.php on line 25

My Code:-

```
<?php
//Recieve username and password from android device or GET request
$user = $_GET['username'];
$pass = $_GET['password'];

//Database connection information
$dbhost = "mysql.hostinger.in";
$dbuser = "u854338141_root";
$dbpass = "1234567";
$dbname = "u854338141_demo";

//Create a connection to databse
$con = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

//Define sql statement for you business logic: registration
$sql = "INSERT into login(username, password) VALUES('" . $user . "', '" . 
$pass . "');

//Execute sql statement
$result = $con->query($sql);

if($result){
echo json_encode(array("Result"=>true));
}else{
echo json_encode(array("Result"=>false));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

change

```
//Define sql statement for you business logic: registration
$sql = "INSERT into login(username, password) VALUES('" . $user . "', '" . 
$pass . "')";
```

add double quote after last bracket

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = "INSERT into login(username, password) VALUES('" . $user . "', '" . 
$pass . "')";
```

You didn't close the query. There is a missing double quote `"` at the end of the query just after the closing bracket.

Comment: Please don't duplicate answers , be more attentive .....

Comment: the only query that he gave. i cannot modified the statement, or the query or the attribute from the original post. The only things that i can do is fixing the missing value, symbol or etc.. It is same when u trying to fixing a words.. Let say someone miss spelled the word airplane, he wrote airplant.. and hes asking whats wrong with the words.. even 10 people answer it, 100% sure they definitely answer AIRPLANE as their answer. And you you come over to those people who answered AIRPLANE and asking them not t duplicate since the only answer is only AIRPLANE..

Comment: Dear @parkway It's not about this specific case, it's generally

Comment: what else did you can change in the query instead of replacing or adding a missing symbol? since the only problem that clearly

Comment: I upvoted your answer , means I agree with your answer , I'm just saying when you see someone already answers don't post same answer that's it , something remains unclear  ?

Comment: i didnt mean to repeating the same things. anyway sorry.

Comment: Everything is ok , anyway thank you too for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

You code is right just add double qoute in the Insert query and your problem solved. Right code is as follows :

```
<?php
//Recieve username and password from android device or GET request
$user = $_GET['username'];
$pass = $_GET['password'];

//Database connection information
$dbhost = "mysql.hostinger.in";
$dbuser = "u854338141_root";
$dbpass = "1234567";
$dbname = "u854338141_demo";

//Create a connection to databse
$con = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

//Define sql statement for you business logic: registration
$sql = "INSERT into login(username, password) VALUES('" . $user . "', '" . 
$pass . "')"; // This line you missed double quote ' " ' 

//Execute sql statement
$result = $con->query($sql);

if($result){
echo json_encode(array("Result"=>true));
}else{
echo json_encode(array("Result"=>false));
}

?>
```

If still you have issue please let us know.